# How do I return a varying number as a variable in a string found in another file that otherwise stays constant (BASH)?

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains text like this (only a portion of it here) and want to find the ATOM # associated with the O5' line (in this case "2"). I would then like to store this number as a variable for future use.  Note that the data below is stored in another file titled "xyz.file" for example. The number of spaces between "ATOM" and the column the number of interest is found in may vary as the number of interest's value changes.

```
ATOM      1 HO5' G5      1       7.415  -9.123  -8.109  1.00  0.00
ATOM      2  O5' G5      1       7.997  -8.960  -8.863  1.00  0.00
ATOM      3  C5' G5      1       9.136  -9.784  -8.729  1.00  0.00
ATOM      4  H5' G5      1       9.679  -9.808  -9.673  1.00  0.00
ATOM      5 H5'' G5      1       8.814 -10.797  -8.484  1.00  0.00
ATOM      6  C4' G5      1      10.067  -9.272  -7.628  1.00  0.00
ATOM      7  H4' G5      1      10.847 -10.015  -7.448  1.00  0.00
ATOM      8  O4' G5      1      10.700  -8.053  -7.990  1.00  0.00
ATOM      9  C1' G5      1      10.866  -7.262  -6.821  1.00  0.00
ATOM     10  H1' G5      1      11.907  -6.970  -6.696  1.00  0.00
ATOM     11  N9  G5      1      10.027  -6.048  -6.896  1.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` one-liner:

```
n=$(awk '$3 == "O5'\''" {print $2; quit}' file)
echo $n
```

prints

```
2
```